# C++ - fgets() ignores subsequent inputs if Enter is pressed

Tags: c++, fgets

I am trying to create an emulator for something, and in the main loop for the processor I wanted to implement a simple way to step the CPU one loop at a time (prompted by pressing Enter each loop) so I can see what instructions are being executed each step. In addition, it allows you to enter a number instead of just Enter to change the default step amount from 1 to something else (so it will skip x number of cycles and then return to 1 at a time afterwards.

The issue is that it works fine when I enter a number (skip that amount of cycles and then prompts me again each cycle), but when I just press Enter rather than entering a number I want it to default to 1 step. Instead, pressing Enter causes it to just run through the whole program without ever prompting me again. How do I make Enter == 1?

```
void CPU_loop()
{
    ...


    static int step = 1;
    char cmd[10];
    if(step == 1)
    {
        if(fgets(cmd, 10, stdin) != NULL) // If you entered something other than Enter; doesn't work
        {
            step = std::atoi(cmd); // Set step amount to whatever you entered
        }
    }
    else
    {
        --step;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just manually read the input from stdin yourself using `getchar`. Just put the text into a buffer until you receive the newline character. Then you can process the text as you wish.

Comment: What is the value of `cmd` when you press Enter? What will then be the value of `step`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press enter directly, it does not default to `1`, but instead you are passing the string `"\n"` to `std::atoi()`, `std::atoi()` cannot be used to perform sanity check on it's input, you can use a different function for that like `std::strtol()` or, you can simply add

```
if (step == 0)
    step = 1;
```

because when, `std::atoi()` takes a `"\n"` as input, it returns `0`. Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) to further understand it.

Quoting the documentation

> Integer value corresponding to the contents of str on success. If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, the return value is undefined. ​**If no conversion can be performed, 0​ is returned**.

One more thing, you could do it the c++ way using streams for input to avoid all this.

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked perfect. The entire time I thought this problem was originating from fgets rather than atoi. I wish I hadn't wasted over an hour trying to fix to wrong problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if (fgets(cmd, 10, stdin) != NULL) 
{
    if (cmd[0] == '\n'){
        step = 1;
    }
    else{
         step = std::atoi(cmd); // Set step amount to whatever you entered
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but if ENTER is pressed, it will pass `"\n"` to `std::atoi()`.

Comment: I am sorry. Edited.